# lists of anagrams in python using two for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a function that takes a list of strings , and return a list that have lists of anagrams words. I need to use 2 for loops for that exercise. Words that are not anagrams to anything will be one item list inside the big list

example output:

```
>>> list_of_words = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']
>>> sort_anagrams(list_of_words)
[['deltas', 'desalt', 'slated', 'salted', 'staled', 'lasted'],
 ['retainers', 'ternaries'], ['pants'], ['generating', 'greatening'], 
['smelters', 'termless', 'resmelts']]
```

im getting the items sorted but dont know how to continue... heres my code:

```
def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
    sorted_list = list()
    temp_list = list()
    temp2_list = list()
    for item in list_of_strings:
        temp_list.append("".join(sorted(item)))
    print(temp_list)
```

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Provide a working [mre]

Comment: @Tomerikoo  i edited the post

Comment: Okay, so do you have an idea for how to determine the anagrams? Did you try searching for this problem?

Comment: well i need to get them sorted and comapre  them afterwards.. i tried  searching for it but didnt find something that include 2 for loops(im taking online course and they asked for that kind of solution)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sort_anagrams(l):
    a,u,x,m=[],[],[],[]
    for i in l:
         i=''.join(sorted(i))
         a.append(i)
    for i in range(len(l)):
         m.append([l[i],a[i]])
    d=list((pair[0],pair[1]) for pair in m)  
    def sorting(s):
        return s[1]

    d=sorted(d, key=sorting)
    count=0
    for i in d:
        if i[1] not in x:
            x.append(i[1])
            u.insert(count,list(list([i[0]])))    
            count+=1
        else:
            u[count-1].append(i[0])    # grouping anagrams together
    return(u)

l = ['deltas', 'retainers', 'desalt', 'pants', 'slated', 'generating', 'ternaries', 'smelters', 'termless', 'salted', 'staled', 'greatening', 'lasted', 'resmelts']

print(sort_anagrams(l))
```

This program would give the result for the list you pass.
edit: I have replace lambda with a function, and zip with a for loop!

Comment: thank you for your help however lambda and zip wasnt wasnt taught so im not supposed to use it.
someone on the forum  of the course told that nested loops are required

Answer (score 0):

hours later, i made it (:
ill post my answer here if someone will need it in the future. feel kinda stupid this simple thing took me so much time

```
def sort_anagrams(list_of_strings):
    sorted_list = list()

    for item in list_of_strings:
        temp_list = list()
        for num in range(len(list_of_strings)):
            if sorted(item) == sorted(list_of_strings[num]) and (item not in sorted_list):
                temp_list.append(list_of_strings[num])
        sorted_list.append(temp_list)

    return(duplicate_remove(sorted_list))


def duplicate_remove(list_to_check):
    final_list = []
    for item in list_to_check:
        if item not in final_list:
            final_list.append(item)
    return final_list
```